# Rotate text to vertical in IE not working

Tags: html, layout, css

I have a table that I need to render some vertical text in one of the columns.

My understanding is that the following style should achieve the effect across browsers:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

This is OK in IE9 and Firefox, however this does not seem to work in IE7 or IE8... See:

http://jsfiddle.net/wzUfj/

Can anybody suggest a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);`
for IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to Rotate in those older browsers, you'll have to use Microsoft's proprietary filters:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=VALUE);
```

Replace Value with an integer, 0-4.

0 = 0 degrees
1 = 90 degrees
2 = 180 degrees
3 = 270 degrees
4 = 360 degrees

I do not believe you can do anything other than 90 degree increments, and I believe you may only have one filter per CSS rule. Also, this is of course non-standard and won't validate, if that's an issue.

Comment: Actually you can, but it's really ugly. You'd need to use Microsoft's matrix transform filter like `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678);`

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transforms - not supported on IE 7 and 8.

See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and below do not support transforms.

According to [this tutorial](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css) you can use writing-mode instead

Answer (score 0):

As an extra gotcha, notice in IE9 the rotation can only be applied to block elements (such as paragraph and not span).

Here is a [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/5QLce/)